# Django python manage.py runserver

Tags: django

I heard that it is not recommended to use

```
python manage.py runserver
```

in a productive environment. How come ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built in Django server is designed for development purposes only. In an actual production environment you'll want to use a robust and powerful alternative, ranging from Apache to nginx using [WSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/) or [mod_python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/howto/deployment/modpython/) etc.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port)

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

A popular setup is keeping nginx in front of [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), which is a WSGI server.